# Formatting code into the style used in Stackoverflow

Tags: formatting, listings, minted

I know that there is `minted` and `listings` for displaying nice code in .tex documents. However, I'd like to use the style that is used for Stackoverflow code: [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667646/python-replace-zeros-in-matrix-with-circle-of-ones). Are there any packages for this, or do I need to create something customized?

Comment: Have you tried using a `tcolorbox` wrapped around your `listings` or `minted` environment? You can use a hook from the `etoolbox` package that automatically embeds your code in such a box. You can set the box to whatever you like, including a plain greyish background.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

stackexchange uses google prettify

https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/wiki/GettingStarted

to format code blocks.

It can't be too hard, if you format your code with that first to convert the generated html markup back to tex, but I don't know of an existing package that does it

**UPDATE**

Note Google has abandoned prettify and stackexchange now uses [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/)

Comment: Wouldn’t it be (much!) easier just to adapt the stylesheet used by Stack Overflow into a minted or listings style definition?

Comment: @KonradRudolph, perhaps but perhaps the context is the OP is using a language for which google does a better job than minted or listings, and writing a new language customisation for  minted might be a lot harder than getting tex to understand the google output. the javascript makes very regular output with no complicated html just specific classes around tokens so latex support for that would be pretty trivial just mapping the classes to fonts/colours

Comment: Okay, that’s of course possible but given the implementation of Google Prettify, I seriously doubt that it performs better than (or even as good as) Pygments lexer definitions – it’s in fact rather primitive for many languages, treating (not so) similar as identical using crude approximations.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'm just answering the question:-)

Comment: It actually uses highlight.js now.

Comment: @Ollie yes not an improvement for tex actually, but hopefully we'll get that improved, but yes I'll update the answer.